# Android Preference. How to force update summary for the preference with SummaryProvider setted?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, preferencefragment, edittextpreference

I have a modified `EditTextPreference` with using `SimpleSummaryProvider`:

```
<NumberPreference
    android:key="pref_key"
    android:defaultValue="0"
    android:title="Some title"
    app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"/>
```

If I change this preference programmatically (for example in the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` event), then the summary in the graphical interface will not update. Is there any way to notify the Preference widget that it needs to read the value again and display it in the summary? Without manually assigning a specific value to the summary?

I am using `PreferenceFragmentCompat` and a modified `EditTextPreference` with a modified `EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the Android sources ([EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/77b8e72/v7/preference/src/android/support/v7/preference/EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java)) - how the dialog for changing settings notifies EditTextPreference about a value change. Did as well and it worked :)

```
if (editTextPreference().callChangeListener(value)) {
    editTextPreference().setText(value);
}
```